# How to generate a Dictionary<> object in c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I want to create a Dictionary<> object and that dictionary object should contains the
name and value properties. For example:

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
```

And when I serialize that dictionary into json string then it should be access like this:

```
dict[0]["name"]=="ProductName"; //property name
dict[0]["value"]=="product1";   // value

dict[1]["name"]=="Description"; //property name
dict[2]["value"]=="product1 desc";   // value

............................
```

But I am not getting the way for it. Can anyone suggest me how can we do that?

**Edit :-**

Actually i am getting the json string from Ajax post like this :-

```
var str ="{"name":"firstName","value":"john"}",
```

And once i get it i am deserialize that string in below format :-

```
var dictDynamic = sear.Deserialize<dynamic>(str);
```

And as a result i am getting the properties like this :

```
dictDynamic[0]["name"]
```

And property value like this :-

```
dictDynamic[0]["value"]
```

But the problem is now i want to do that on server side.Means want to generate model string in above json string format and after that want to deserialize in the mentioned manner.

Comment: use a Json parser like `JSON.NET`

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary does not allow you to have two keys with the same value. So `0` as a key does not work.

Probably the best thing to do is create an object to hold your information.

```
public class Product
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then create some objects.

```
Product product=new Product();
product.ID="0";
product.Name="My Super Widget";
product.Value="500";
//Then add that product to the dictionary.
Dictionary<string, Product> products=new Dictionary<string, Product>();
products.Add(product.ID, product);
//then you can access it in this way
products["0"].Name; //the value of this is "My Super Widget"
```

Want to serialize it to JSON? Let's use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

```
string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
```

Comment: ,i want to access the data by this way str[0]["name"] and str[0]["value"] after deseariliazation.Where "name" is the property name and "value" is the value of that property.And it's not necessary to use Dictionary.

Comment: @Pawan Your question specifically asks how to create a dictionary in C# and then how to serialize that to a JSON string. Unfortunately, the syntax you've posted for accessing the resulting object is not valid. And you have not provided anything describing why you want to access the object in that manner. Perhaps you should update the question to clearly explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ,i have updated my question.And i want to do it like this because of the old structure of application.And i can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

But you need to have a valid dictionary and serializable values., e.g.:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };
dict["0"] = product;
```

Comment: ,my problem is when i DeSerialize the string then i am getting the "Key" and "Value" but i need "name" instead of "Key" according to old code.So how can we do that ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Can you maybe extend your question and explain a littel more, what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

var innerDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
innerDict.Add("name", "name 0");
innerDict.Add("value", "value 0");

myDict.Add("0", innerDict);

innerDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
innerDict.Add("name", "name 1");
innerDict.Add("value", "value 1");

myDict.Add("1", innerDict);

var foo = myDict["0"]["name"]; // returns "name 0"

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict);
```

Comment: It's helpful if you explain your code and how it may help the OP, rather than just dumping it on the page.